# how to calculate distance of a set of geo points using sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, google-maps, geo

i have a set of longitude and latitude that saved in database, now i want to calculate Travelled distance in a period of time .i want write this query in oracle 11g.

my table fields are

```
GeoData Table fields:

Latitude : FLOAT
Longitude: FLOAT
insert_time: TIMESTAMP(6)
```

i want to pass from date and to date to this query and select calculated distance .

thanks  in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try it. I think it will help you.

```
"SELECT ((ACOS(SIN($latitude * PI() / 180) * SIN(Latitude * PI() / 180) + COS($latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(Latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(($longitude - Longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance`  FROM `table_name` "
```

where $latitude=> current latitude and $longitude=> current longitude

Comment: It will calculate the list of distance between the current location and the stored database value. The distance will be calculated between two points only.

Comment: what do you mean current location :i expect a query like this :select distance from myTable where insert_time between(date1,date2)

Comment: Current location means current latitude and current longitude.

Comment: i ran this query  :SELECT ((ACOS(SIN(latitude * 3.14 / 180) * SIN(latitude * 3.14 / 180) + COS(latitude * 3.14 / 180) * COS(latitude * 3.14 / 180) * COS((longitude - longitude) * 3.14 / 180)) * 180 / 3.14) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance
FROM avl_data where car_id=301 and time> to_date ('14-JUN-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY');

Comment: but it returns this exception :ORA-01428: argument '1.00000000000000000000000000000000000002' is out of range
01428. 00000 -  "argument '%s' is out of range"

Comment: You have written all latitude and longitude as table's field name. But I have mention $latitude,Latitude and $longitude,Longitude where $latitude, $longitude are the supplied value and Latitude,Longitude are the table's field name.

Comment: how to i use insert_time in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Atanu Mondal worked almost flawlessly.

However I've got the same problem of user1738224 and I also needed the distance in Kilometers, not in miles, so I chanded the formula to

```
SELECT ((ACOS(ROUND(SIN($latitude * PI() / 180) * SIN(Latitude * PI() / 180) + COS($latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(Latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(($longitude - Longitude) * PI() / 180), 35)) * 180 / 3.141592653 ) * 60 * 1.8531) AS Distance FROM `table_name`
```

Hope this helps.